# Migrating closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, migration, moderator-tools

Sometimes a question gets closed as off-topic (not-migrated) while there is another site where the question is on-topic.

If a moderator wants to migrate the question, the moderator needs to reopen the question and then reclose it as off-topic and migrate the question.

It would nice if a moderator can migrate questions closed as off-topic without going through this process of reopening/reclosing.

Comment: Well, if it got several non-migration close votes it's unlikely to be a great question, and generally only great questions should be migrated.  If it already has problems, it probably shouldn't be migrated.

Comment: I agree. The example I linked to though, notice that there is a comment saying this question belongs on SO and it has 4 up votes. How can I tell how many people put that as their close reason?

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to [voteraq7's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140574/140951), it's not that much of an edge case on Stack Overflow.  Granted, moderators get to the question usually *before* it's closed as OT, but in the cases where we do, the aggregate savings from having a feature like this would be very beneficial.

Unfortunately, that means that you'd have to somehow renable the close link (it turns to "reopen" when closed) so that you can get to the OT dialog.  That would mean an extra link when the question is closed, and real estate is scarce.

That said, if they could address the above, I'm for it.

Comment: Is there really a preponderance of questions on SO (or any other site) which are closed that are also *good enough* to warrant migration? Like I said in my answer, when stuff gets closed on SF it's generally crap I wouldn't want to dump on any other site. (Frankly some of the stuff that escapes out of our  migration paths is pretty much crap too...)

Comment: @voretaq7 I do a number of migrations a day.  There are those that are rejected (I don't have the stats on them), but we have questions that aren't total crap which are migrated.

Comment: I'm not doubting that there are good migrations, I'm asking how many of the questions that are **closed** (OT or otherwise) are really *worthy* of being migrated. (Leaving aside the non-trilogy sites without a populated migration list -- I think the solution there is to open reasonable migration paths for them...)

Answer (score 4):

The OP can repost on the correct site.  That's the only other way to move the question, although, since it doesn't go through the usual migration cycle, it's not a genuine migration (no referral link is provided, for one thing).

Comment: Merged with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140571/migrating-closed-questions

Answer (score 2):

> In the past I have been reopening the question and then closing and migrating it. It seems like there should be a better way.

Not really; that's pretty straightforward already. Given the lack of clear down-sides and, frankly, the rarity of such migrations in the first place, I don't see that a specialized tool for this is needed.

If you ever find yourself needing to migrate a *lot* of questions to another site (whether currently closed or open) get in touch with one of us on the SE team - we do have tools for bulk migration. Then again, the only time you'd need this would be your site being closed or [another site breaking off from it and then graduating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site), so... Probably not something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the issue is related to that [question, tagged bug, on meta.crypto](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/555).

For **some** users (including with high reputation on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), perhaps all non-moderators) the user interface allowing to register a close vote with request for migration among a choice of sites fails to show, as I think I remember it did some time ago.

Update: perhaps that vague souvenir was really on another site, without beta status.

Comment: Merged with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140571/migrating-closed-questions

Answer (score 0):

This is such a corner case I don't really mind it.

Most of what gets closed (OT or otherwise) is really crap and not worth migrating -- I think I've only had a site ask me to migrate a question that was closed on SF once, and the extra 5 seconds to re-open and re-close/migrate doesn't bother me that much.

Just my $3.50

Comment: this is not a major issue on trilogy because the migration paths between them are open. If they were not, ordinary users could not migrate questions when closing as off-topic and the issue would become more common, as is the case on some other sites.

Comment: Should we perhaps have site-specific settings for commonly used migration paths, something the [diamond] mods on each site could vote for? I mean, I can see a possible migration path set up between [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Kaveh AFAIK There's nothing (technical) stopping non-trilogy sites from having the same style of off-topic migration target lists as the trilogy sites do.  Perhaps a better solution would be getting the devs to populate your migration lists? :-)

Comment: @voretaq7, (the problem is not *technical*) we are thinking asking SE to add one or two most common migration destinations to the list. Meanwhile and a part from that I still think this can be a useful feature. ps: most questions closed on our side are not crap but just off-topic.