# Too old to migrate this post?

Tags: discussion, migration, community-wiki, old-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039904/what-statistics-should-a-programmer-or-computer-scientist-know), in my opinion, is a clear candidate for moving to Programmers but is too old to mark it as such (it is also a community wiki, which is probably another factor).

What is the appropriate action for it? Is it something that could be migrated, or is it something that should be left alone? I came across it a few minutes ago and thought I'd ask.

I realize the long-standing argument has been that old questions aren't really relevant/useful (i.e. it'd be pointless to migrate), but I personally found the post quite useful and probably would have found it sooner on Programmers rather than StackOverflow since I browse Programmers on my spare time much more often.

Comment: There's always going to be overlap between the sites, as Stackoverflow and Programmers share some of that.  But, it's still too old...

Comment: Yes, but this question is a) very off topic for the specific guidelines of StackOverflow, and b) active as of only 23 days ago. It's still kicking.

Comment: I don't really see how it's off-topic, given its age and relevance to programming.

Comment: Stackoverflow is meant to be for QA about [*specific issues you're facing*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), not for open-ended discussion.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a historical lock.

Comment: @Qix The question is extremely broad, I don't think it's a good fit for Programmers.

Comment: @Yannis It's a better fit than StackOverflow. A post like that would more than likely end up on Programmers if it were to be posted today. I think there's a fine line between SO and Programmers, and this one definitely fits on the line of Programmers; it asks a *generalized programming question* instead of a specific language/code/service/etc. related issue.

Comment: @Yannis per the [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange) on SO vs. Programmers, this is a *perfect* candidate for migration.

Comment: @Qix It's a better fit for Programmers than SO, but it's _not_ a good question in _general_ (at least by the _current_ standards), it's extremely broad.

Comment: @Yannis - True; so it goes back to my original question of 'what is the appropriate action'?

Comment: @Qix Leave it where it is, and _if_ it gets closed, then perhaps a historical lock might be appropriate.

Comment: What do I flag it as? Non constructive, or off topic, or..?

Comment: @Qix Why flag it at all? It's not a bad question, just let it be... If it must be closed, let it be closed naturally.

Comment: Because it would better benefit both sites by migrating it. It's still pretty active and is viewed quite a bit; it has also accumulated a large number of up-votes and has a lot of really good information in it that better belongs on Programmers.

Comment: @Qix There's no way that question will be migrated to Programmers, I thought that was clear by now. It's extremely broad, it's _not_ a good question for Programmers, even if it's more on topic there than SO.

Comment: And yet there's been no clear statement as to why other than 'just leave it be'.

Comment: @Qix What?! Too broad, off topic (not a real question) for Programmers. Simple as that.

Comment: Then why do I see questions on programmers asking pretty much the same thing all the time? Should I be flagging those questions?

Comment: @Qix If they are equally broad, yes please.

Comment: Then let me go [flag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180212/good-implementation-strategies-for-encapsulating-shared-data-in-a-software-pipel) [the](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180320/have-i-understood-oop-correctly) [entirety](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175824/quality-assurance-activities) [of](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179051/what-are-abstract-classes-and-abstract-methods) [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179473/asking-potential-developers-to-draw-uml-diagrams-during-the-interview)...

Comment: Those are *all* equally as broad. That's just a few on the **first page**. I'd also like more than one opinion on this, Yannis.

Comment: @Qix The one question you linked to is about to be closed (4 close votes), and I disagree on the others.

Comment: @Yannis Doesn't it kill you that people *still* don't know what P.SE is for?  I sympathize with you man.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Well to be fair to Qix, most of the secondary questions in the question would indeed be better fitting for ProgSE than SO (topically). That said, the third question, "What resources should I use to learn this?" makes me shiver...

Comment: I know exactly what Programmers is for, @Jolly.

Answer (score 6):

Migration is not an option:

1. [Migration for questions older than 60 days is disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) <sup>*</sup>,
2. The question is incredibly broad, even if it's more suitable for ProgSE than SO, it's not suitable for Stack Exchange in general. If it was asked on Programmers today, I'm afraid I'd have to close it.

Right now the only appropriate action for the question is closure, and perhaps a historical lock (if it gets closed). That said, it's a good question, and it has some great answers, there would be little point in closing it unless it becomes unmaintainable (crap later answers, etc).

<sub><sup>*</sup> [How to migrate old questions to a new graduated site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site).</sub>

Comment: Just chiming in, this would not be migrated even if migration wasn't blocked. It's simply too broad for Programmers.

Comment: Also, not big on a historical lock for this. I prefer to see six digits in page views if I'm going to do that, personally.