# Should questions about Magento be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions

Should questions about Magento be flagged for migration. New questions of course. I know http://magento.stackexchange.com is in beta, but should we flag to migrate questions to there?

Comment: That's a lot of flags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento

Comment: @MikeB I meant just new ones, that are asked... I think it would help their beta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.** Just because the questions may now be on-topic for another site doesn't make them any less on-topic for Stack Overflow. They should remain on the site the user asked them on. If the question doesn't fit into the scope of one site but does fit into the scope of the other, *then* they should be migrated.

Comment: In addition to this, why swamp a new site with old questions? Let it figure itself out first and if they later want to move some questions over, they can follow [this process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site).

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, I was just referring to newer questions.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the Magento community, but when I look at the garbage that comes in on the tag on SO ("My boss told me to implement feature xyz in Magento how to do plz send code") I'd say the Magento site will have to be very careful about quality, and routinely migrating questions from SO may hurt it more than help it.

The first rule we all should have in mind is **don't migrate crap**, even if a question would be on-topic on the receiving site and is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that [magento] seems to attract an incredible number of spammers. I don't know what it is about that tag, but I've spent hours cleaning up spam rings there.