# How to redirect users to an alternate Stack Exchange for questions that were formerly answered on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, migration, migration-path-request

## Question

Are there any general best practices for when a SO tag gets its own Stack Exchange?  Specifically, (1) migrating questions with that tag to the new Stack Exchange, and (2) directing users to post new questions there?

## Specific Instance: [Salesforce] -> salesforce.stackexchange.com

About a year ago salesforce.stackexchange.com was launched and has effectively replaced the salesforce tag on Stack Overflow.  Looking at the [area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce) it seems reasonable to assume that most of the traffic is going there, but a lot of users are still posting to SO, and a fair number of search engine traffic goes to SO.

Are there other examples of this sort of scenario we can draw on?  What was done in those cases?

### Full list of related tags

- [salesforce](/questions/tagged/salesforce)
- [apex-code](/questions/tagged/apex-code)
- [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce)
- [force.com](/questions/tagged/force.com)
- [soql](/questions/tagged/soql)

Comment: Yeah, salesforce (along with a couple of other salesforce related tags), must have buried the lead by putting that in the Background section of my question.

Comment: There is frequently overlap between stack exchange sites.  While 1 particular site might take "most" of the traffic for a specific tag.  Other might get equal traffic (or SO still might get more).  How you propose that be handled.

Comment: My thoughts, we're 1) people flagging questions for migration, 2) commenting to users about the new site, and 3) hopefully there are some other ideas from the SO Meta community

Comment: "formally" is the part pf your question i have an issue with.  Just because a new on-topic SE site is launched doesn't automatically make questions off-topic.  It is possible questions are on-topic on 2 sites.  So why should anythign be done is if the question is on-topic for SO?

Comment: @psub It seems to be this is a pretty natural course of things.  If we have two places to put things (1) the same questions tend to get asked twice (2) you can't mark stuff as duplicates that is on another site, (3) splits the focus of the user community.  I'd be interesting to hear your thoughts from the other direction (since that's the side I don't know), why wouldn't we migrate questions that are specifically targetted to a new stackexchange?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> migrating questions with that tag to the new stackexchange

Old questions should stay. Except in a special case, which I'll get to later

> directing users to post new questions there?

This depends. Has the community shifted over, too? When an SE beta is created, they know that they have to compete with the overlap sites. With this in mind, it's perfectly OK for the community to stay put instead of migrating over. In the case of some sites, that has happened and the new site has formed its own community from scratch.

In that case, don't direct people there. **The creation of a new site doesn't necessarily make stuff off topic on the old one.**

In cases of sites like [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com), where the community wasn't too happy with SO, almost the entire community moved over to the new site. In this case, redirecting the OP to the new site is great.

In addition, you may also be able to get the old questions migrated, using the [one time migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site) procedure.

Comment: *"The creation of a new site doesn't necessarily make stuff off topic on the old one"* <--- that!

Comment: That line should honestly be in bold.

Comment: Looking at the stats, there are 3 or so questions per day being asked on the SO tag, in comparison to 20 or so per day on the SE site.  Additionally, most posts to SO are from brand new users.  Do you feel that would qualify as the "community shifting"?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on one time migration