# Why are a lot of should-have-been-on-MSO questions closed instead of migrated back?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta, mso-mse-split

I learned that [MSO and MSE split up in Mid 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/350567), and since then a lot of good questions were closed as ***pertains only to a specific site***. Some even have comments below claiming

> To be clear, this question was originally posted on MSO ...

By "originally", I mean those good posts that were posted on MSE **before the split**. They were posted in 2011, last active in 2013, and closed in 2015 and so on. A list of examples can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1+%5Bstackoverflow%5D&tab=votes)

Why aren't they sent back to MSO? They would have been received positively there (and even here already: some has 20+ score).

Comment: If we need the question on MSO, for example because a new question is asked but the duplicate is still on MSE, it is early enough to migrate. That prevents that someone has to sit down and migrate everything, including the crap.

Comment: @rene Those with tens or even hundreds of votes surely aren't crap.

Comment: sure, but if we didn't miss them so far on MSO I think we're good.

Answer (score 10):

Migrating posts that are older than 60 days is *hard* and [it's that way intentionally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

> Migration works best as a way to salvage good but off-topic questions and give them new life on a site where they can thrive. But shuffling old, answered, on-topic questions around for the hell of it is a waste of everyone's time.
>
> Therefore, I think the real solution is much simpler: just disable the migration of old questions. They're rarely welcomed or heavily improved post-migration, often overtly disliked by folks on the destination site, and can end up causing a rather bad experience for folks who were participating in good faith on the original.

This was implemented back in 2012.

There was also a [statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site) from Adam Lear shortly after it was implemented here:

> One of the key guidelines for migrating questions (after "don't migrate crap") is "don't migrate old, answered questions".

And it continues:

> 3. We will do a **one-time** mass migration of the questions that make the cut. This has some additional implications. For example, your front page on the smaller site will be more or less destroyed for a bit, so make each question count.
>
> Once this migration happens, the topic is closed. There will be no more discussions, migrations, exceptions, etc. where old questions are concerned. You're free to still edit and migrate new questions if needed.
>
> **What happens if some of the questions you wanted don't get migrated?** Just treat the original site [like you would any external blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way). If someone asks a similar question on your site and you're certain that you can't do better than the original version elsewhere, *summarize it, give credit to the author, and link back to the original*.

(Note that they don't really do this any more, it's only relative to this question about why it hasn't been done)

So, between it being practically difficult and it being against policy, and I'll add to that, time consuming and low priority...

#### We keep them here.

---

There are no migration paths set up between Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow.

In fact, there's not even an option the way there is on all other sites to migrate anywhere, likely because there is no meta Meta Stack Exchange.

[image: No migration option]

So... that means that **users** have no way to close and migrate to Meta Stack Overflow because not only is there no migration pathway for Meta Stack Overflow... there's no migration *option*.

This means that the only way something can be migrated away to any site, Meta Stack Overflow or not, is for the Staff to do it - the developers and community managers who have diamonds on Meta Stack Exchange are the only people who can migrate questions away from MSE... and they do, occasionally:

[image: Migrations away from MSE]

You can see there have been 18 sent to Meta Stack Overflow, two to Stack Apps, and one each to Server Fault Meta and Physics Meta over the last 90 days.

In that same 90 days, 63 questions have been closed as "pertains only to a specific site".

[image: Close stats for "pertains only to a specific site"]

In the grand scheme of total questions closed, that's pretty low... but, in order to get something migrated to another meta from Meta Stack Exchange, you'd have to:

1. Recognize that the question pertains to another site **and** that it's worthy of migration (many may not be).
2. Flag the post for moderator attention using a custom flag asking it to be migrated.
3. Wait for one of the staff to check the flags and agree that it's high-quality enough and hasn't already been re-posted on MSO.
4. They reopen the post (if it was closed in the interim) and migrate it.

Staff are a bit busy with other things. As you can see, 18 posts *were* migrated, but that's often because the staff member was already around when it was posted and is able to deal with it quickly. Often, I find that Jobs-related questions are migrated, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303904/developer-jobs-search-filter-for-listings-with-an-easy-apply-button?noredirect=1) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303368/filter-out-jobs-applied-for-and-rejected-in-last-n-number-days?noredirect=1), sometimes by Jobs team members who are able to migrate them to Meta Stack Overflow and then answer them.

The vast majority of questions I see closed as "pertains only to a specific site", though, are users coming to Meta Stack Exchange to complain about something on a specific site, not actually users looking for honest help. These aren't good candidates for migration.

Comment: You're misreading my question. I specifically meant those of good quality and exist for several years.

Comment: I've edited... but if I'm still missing what you're asking, perhaps add more of an explanation to your question? A specific example, maybe?

Comment: I have added a list (via search)

Comment: Its worth considering - if its really useful and *over there*, you can always reask, updated for a specific, "modern" problem linking back to the question there. MSO to MSE was really a tough move, and needed to deal with a ton of 'organisational debt' - considering the changes from the first meta to what we have today. I don't think its the best use of SO mod and staff time to try to save it all.

Answer (score 6):

There is no migration path from here to site-specific metas. Any migration from Meta Stack Exchange would have to be done by Meta Stack Exchange moderators. If you have a strong case for something to be migrated, you can raise a moderator-attention flag stating your case. But consider first:

1. The only moderators here are Stack Exchange employees who are busy doing whatever they are paid to do (which is generally not migrating questions between sites). Don't expect moderator-attention flags to be handled quickly.
2. The value of a pre-2014 discussion materializing on another meta may be less than you think. Even if it's a good question, it has a baggage of answers and votes that reflect the prevailing mood of another era. If Meta SO really needs such a discussion in 2017, it should start on a clean slate in 2017 (soon to be 2018...), not start adding notes on the margins of an ancient tome. And there's a good chance that it did so already, and the migrated post would be a duplicate.