# Where do I get a community for a proposal?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, community

For a proposal I need *200 people*. My Question is simple: Where do I find them?

Is there any site, or other social network for proposing stack sites or similar to this use?

Comment: I've seen the answer there, went on the [final link](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/how-do-i-create-a-new-community-on-stack-exchange), but it's again assuming that you can create one from blank. It's not the answer that is given below, which states that you WILL NEVER BE ABLE TO START A COMMUNITY (sadly), so I believe it's an independent question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have the community already, getting the proposal through and building a site would be impossible.

A few communities actually started off as their own Q&A sites - two of our Russian sites for example. Others already had a community - Operations Research comes to mind, and they also had a Q&A site earlier.

If you need to *look* for a community, you're not there. If you know a community for the subject - say Reddit, or forums, or preexisting Q&A sites which could *benefit* from being under the SE umbrella - that's the place to start.

The work isn't in finding 200 people interested in a subject. It's to know a place with N people with a enough people interested in a Stack Exchange Q&A site, and hopefully being able to also draw experienced folks from other sites on the network to help with mechanics.

So you might be starting at the wrong point.

Comment: Would it be possible to post this answer under the [older question on the same topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309634/321340)? This one is close to being closed as a duplicate, and this answer would get more visibility there. I'd be happy to see this there.

Comment: Done. I might edit the answer there to be more specific later