# Be extra helpful to new users

Tags: discussion, new-users, off-topic, ethics

I generally don't participate much on SO or Meta. This is not a new case but I can't just prevent myself from posting this.

Let's look at this question:

[PHP CURL not loading in WAMP after upgrading PHP from 5.3.4 to 5.3.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029083/php-curl-not-loading-in-wamp)  by a [new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001220/user3001220)

The OP of the question appears to have done his research, and tried several things before posting here. Instead of the help he was expecting, he received two comments; one advising to post it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and another to post it on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

After some time the question was closed, stating the reason as *off-topic*. But I am unsure many similar questions like [PHP CURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit)  manage to be *on-topic*, although both of them are not programming related questions. Also, remember that the similar question with upvotes inspired user to post it here.

Let's look at the advice given to the user:

> put on hold as off-topic by arkascha, M42, zero323, halfer, rene 2 days ago
>   This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave these specific reasons:
>
> "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault." – halfer, rene
>
> "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User." – arkascha, M42, zero323

The close reasons advise the user to post it on two different sites. From this, we can see that even old SO users are confused as to which is the correct place to post this between Server Fault and Super User....so how can you expect a new user who has just joined today to understand this very well?

Then, I waited for 2 days to see if the OP will post it on a different SE site or not. The result was **No**. The user didn't post it again on a different SE site.

Well, this is one of the numerous cases in which new users are unwelcomed here, and many eventually never return to this site. So, my request is that we should help new users to understand this site and not just create a pile of downvotes or closing their questions without helping them.

P.S. Can anyone explain while [PHP CURL not loading in WAMP after upgrading PHP from 5.3.4 to 5.3.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029083/php-curl-not-loading-in-wamp) was off-topic why [PHP cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit) is on-topic?

---

**Update:**

My intention by sharing this question was neither to limit this discussion to this question nor to start a debate about WAMP questions. The linked question was not downvoted but there are lot of questions who get lot of downvotes without reason written. Also, here *extra helpful* means spending extra efforts helping new users understand the site. I have also included an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208047/219322) with my suggestions but it is somehow downvoted.

Comment: There is a difference between a question asking for an outside resource and one asking about a problem without expectation of what the solution may be.

Comment: Sorry, but not sure what you suggest instead. There were no downvotes involved. No rude comments. It looks just fine and polite to me.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to discourage people encouraging reposting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195008/how-to-discourage-people-encouraging-reposting)

Comment: Consider also the possibility that the user needed the answer *now* and an answer the next day (or reasking on another site) isn't helpful... or they discovered the solution and didn't post an answer for it themselves.

Comment: A well researched question, where multiple attempts had been, about building a rocking chair would likely get the same response.

Comment: @MichaelT If they needed an answer now they should have been following the question and the responses to it, rather than waiting a day to find out that they posted on the wrong site.  If they realized their mistake and reposted when they got their first comment, they would have lost very little time.

Comment: It might help to refocus this question on what difference there is between the [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029083/php-curl-not-loading-in-wamp) and the [open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit) questions. Closing questions is not "inappropriate behavior", there is no "pile of downvotes," and it has nothing to do with the user being new, so I think those distract from a worthwhile question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not in this case, but I am talking about other cases too

Comment: @Servy the question was posted at 9:18, the first comment at 9:53 and the second comment at 10:53.  If they had the expectation of someone pulling out FGITW and giving them an answer in 5 minutes they might have gotten bored waiting for over half an hour for some activity on the question and left.

Comment: We really need to find a name for the endless arguments "If this is on topic why this isn't"... it all boils down to the fact Stack Overflow changed over time plus it consists of variety of programmers, each with his own personal opinions. Nothing we can do but contribute our own small part.

Comment: OK... the most likely answer to your 'PS' is that if both questions are off topic (putting aside the question about whether they really are or not for now) then the most likely result of you drawing attention to the old one is that *both* will end up being closed. This isn't "discrimination" (as you used the term in your answer below), just simply an imperfect moderation system that sometimes misses old questions.

Comment: `The user didn't post it again on a different SE site.` and you're saying that is *our* fault?

Comment: @MichaelT They also can have email notifications for comments to their question, which makes it easy to keep track, and checking in on it every half hour or hour for the first few hours, if it really is an important issue, would be reasonable.  I would expect someone to just ignore it for a whole day if it was a very important very time sensitive issue.  Of course, if it's not time sensitive, then that's their decision to make.

Comment: @probablyPekka Confusing user by giving random advise is our fault

Comment: I voted to close and did suggest the professional server and networking site because it already metioned all kind of configuration of apache and php dlls which to me seemed not a general issue, but a specific configuration issue either on OS level or in apache, hence better sduited for the pro's

Comment: @VarunAgw The users sincerely felt that the question belonged on another side, and their comments were polite and clear.  If they made an honest mistake in their determination of the site the question belongs in then you simply need to comment with your own polite and helpful comment providing your thoughts on where the question belongs and why.  There is no need to call out these users as you have done, as their actions are not at all inappropriate, abusive, insulting, or anything like that.

Comment: @rene: the problem is, this isn't about a production Apache or PHP installation; it's specifically concerned with [a prepackaged development environment](http://www.wampserver.com/) based on those tools. SF is generally resistant to such questions, as both the baseline knowledge and desired goals are very different.

Comment: @rene I'm commenting as a SF reg -- we generally regard WAMP and LAMP posts badly as they tend to make for bad questions and quite often end up off-topic.

Comment: So we consider WAMP and LAMP to be development tools in the context of SO.

Comment: I tend to, @rene. Feel free to weigh in [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208052/do-questions-on-wamp-belong-on-so-sf-or-su) if you disagree but generally-speaking I would lump it in with tools like Emacs.

Comment: @shawiz - Sounds a lot like [this girl](http://educationaladvancement.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/thats-just-not-fair/#more-719). The issue is that many people want the world to consist of [logical imperatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_logic). They see a "rule" or "policy" on our site and then immediately see examples where this imperative was inconsistently acted upon. "Close all off-topic questions" followed by two nearly identical questions treated very differently - there's no consistency, violating the logic of the imperatives.

Comment: @ShaWiz - as to what to call such posts, it is in essence a call to develop more logical imperatives ("policies", "rules", etc.). Since it sounds so much like the whining of a preadolescent child, we could call it a "tween imperative". That's a bit mean, though, since sometimes there is a legitimate mismatch between policy and practice.

Comment: @JDB good points and a fine name! :)

Answer (score 26):

They politely told the user that the question is offtopic and where to go to get help.  If the user decided that getting an answer to their question wasn't worth posting it on the appropriate site, that is their decision to make.

There were no downvotes (despite rather good reason for doing so) there were no rude comments, and the user was pointed to the correct place.  I don't see what could possibly have been done *better*.

Comment: +1 When clicking on this question I was expecting horrible comments, instead I saw a perfectly fine handling of the question.

Comment: What I'm wondering about is why the original question, which the poster explicitly states is the same problem, is *not* considered OT and in fact has >100 upvotes.

Comment: @Stijn I actually wasn't surprised.  If there were really rude comments to the author I would have expected Varun to mention them in this meta post.  The fact that he chose to quite two comments, and those comments were entirely appropriate, I was not surprised to see only more helpful comments on the actual question.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar 1) That a question doesn't get closed doesn't mean it's on topic 2) Sometimes exceptions are made, and a borderline or slightly offtopic post is allowed to stay if it has sufficiently valuable content 3) standards change over time, usually narrowing, not expanding.  Regardless, it's not my area of expertise, so I leave it to others to consider whether it should be closed or not.

Answer (score 16):

First off, SU and SF are generally not great places for WAMP questions... Particularly when asked on SO, these nearly always involve someone working with their development or testing setup (rather than, say, a home or production server environment). If you see someone recommending SF or SU for such questions, politely correct them.

Second, if you're concerned about a question or the advice given to its asker *don't sit on your hands for two days* - try to fix it! It took me just a few minutes to leave polite comments correcting those who recommended SF and SU, and a minute more to edit the question to clarify the title and fix the multiple formatting issues that plagued it. I then voted to reopen it.

As a low-reputation user on Stack Overflow, there's a limit to how much you can accomplish - but you *do* have the privilege to comment everywhere, and you *can* suggest edits that improve the clarity of any post. **Use these privileges** when you see something wrong.

Comment: Well said, but looks like some user(s) on SO still don't agree with you and trying to close the question again. (Wait.. did you clear the close votes?)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've removed my comment and retracted my vote and am now typing up a separate Meta question.

Comment: @Stijn fair enough. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 5):

I may be reiterating some of the points already made, but since my name has been taken in vain `;)`, I feel entitled to make a couple of points on this case.

The suggestion that I have made a new user feel unwelcome is a little frustrating, especially since I frequently come down on the side of that particular debate as "let's be more civil to new users". That can easily be checked from my posting history here and on SO.

I voted to close this question and recommended Server Fault, but have since been informed that the question would not be welcome there anyway. I would still be minded to regard it as off-topic for Stack Overflow, except that more experienced users have voted to reopen it; I shall therefore try to remember that this *particular* item of server software is regarded as a programming tool, and will refrain from closing such topics in future.

Your sentiment that we should be more welcoming generally of new users is fine in theory, but try commenting on 1-rep user questions for a couple of years, and you'll soon change your mind. Me, I'm a sucker for punishment, as I [frequently comment on off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer?tab=activity&sort=comments) and, of first-time posts, I'd estimate that 95%+ don't bother replying to my gentle advice. I am not sure there is much more I can do, in all honesty.

For what it's worth, I think Stack Overflow (at least the tags I primarily spend time in) is mainly striking the correct balance. The community certainly should be remaining civil, but challenging lazy [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) on the web is also a worthwhile aim, and I've not heard of any other site that is dealing with it as effectively.

Now, if you find comments or answers that are being hostile to new users then report them using the flag system (even if those comments come from high-rep members). I frequently make such reports, and sometimes will additionally comment to assuage some hurt feelings (even if the OP is then disinclined to reply). You can do the same too, if you would like to help new users in the tags you most read.

Comment: Interesting point, halfer:  "...of first-time posts, I'd estimate that 95%+ don't bother replying to my gentle advice..."  In the past 24-hours, I ran into 2 migrated questions, where the **question** was migrated, but the user's **logon** was not "migrated" or setup on the new site... and the user has not replied/participated since.  I was starting to wonder if MIGRATION itself causes any technical difficulties, with a user being able to post comments / reply / edit question, etc., on their own question.   (If you see that as a real concern, I can post it as a new Meta question.)

Comment: P.S. The 2 example questions I am referring to, are http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53579/sql-server-replication-setting-up-scheduler-issue/53587#53587, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077340/ssrs-report-timeout.  For both, the OP on the question appears grayed out, and is not clickable.

Comment: My point was referring specifically to people who have a Stack Overflow account, and whose question was put on hold rather than migrated. There would be no reason for their not replying other than (a) they never log on again, or (b) they lose interest and choose not to reply. Both cases are probably part of the something-for-nothing crowd that we are best not trying to cater for, imo.

Comment: In terms of those DBA examples, it seems that everything went as well as one could ask for; they were off-topic for SO and were successfully migrated to another SE site (i.e. they are presented to an audience that is better placed to answer them). If the user logs onto SE and clicks on these questions, they will be asked if they want a DBA account created automatically. If they can't or won't do that, again there's not much we can do.

Comment: Thx:  you answered my *technical* question, with: "If the user logs onto SE and clicks on these questions, they will be asked if they want a DBA account created automatically..."  The SO question that was migrated from dba *TO* stackoverflow could be from the "something for nothing" crowd (little effort in the question);  but the question that was migrated to dba *FROM* stackoverflow reflects effort, both in their question, and in their work before coming here... which leaves me wondering how "extra helpful to new users" `;)` the account auto-creation is.  Thx in any case, for the reply.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that the second item was migrated _to_ Stack Overflow. Yes, no effort has been demonstrated in the question, and readers even have to click on a third-party link to read the code. That should not have been migrated in my view, but then one of the key topics here is that even experienced mods/readers make non-ideal migration decisions `:-)`.

Comment: I've made some comments on that question, and voted to put on hold.

Comment: Good comments -- upvoted them.  Question: are there design-reasons why searching SO for `migrated:yes answers:1` returns *zero* results?  I searched on that after noticing `migrated:yes` was returning unanswered only, (and was starting to wonder, again, if migration introduced tech difficulties for the OP).

Comment: I don't know, to be honest - I can't imagine there are no migrated (to Stack Overflow) questions that don't have exactly one answer. You could ask a question in chat somewhere (MSO chat, if it exists) or start a new post here on MSO. I've not tried it, myself.

Comment: FYI I posted it as a new question, **[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208270/is-there-a-design-reason-why-migratedyes-answers1-returns-zero-results)**