# Is there a design reason, why `migrated:yes answers:1` returns zero results?

Tags: discussion, search, migration

1. On StackOverflow, if you type `migrated:yes answers:1` in the search box, it returns zero results.  (Based on the mini-help, I would understand `answers:1` to select anything with *1 or more* answers.)

   This may be a simple bug, or simple question of understanding the use of those criteria during searching... but FYI, it came out of a larger question:
2. *Does migration of a question pose any **technical** hurdles to the Original Poster, if that OP does not yet have an account, on the migration-target-site?*

`halfer` started answering that question, under topic *Be extra helpful to new users*, in comments *[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208042/be-extra-helpful-to-new-users/208111#comment663743_208111)*, where he pointed out that

> If the user logs onto SE and clicks on these questions, they will be asked if they want a [migration target site] account created automatically.

I'm just wondering if their capabilities are even more limited, as a new user who doesn't even have points for asking a question, on the migration site.

**EDIT:**
I just accepted ShaWizDowArd's answer re' (1)--the title question--and checked the search help page, which does say `migrated` "returns only questions that have been migrated **to** a different site", where I had been searching for "migrated **from**".

Comment: I find your parenthese confusing...

Comment: There is no minimal reputation requirement to ask a question, so *as a new user who doesn't even have points for asking a question, on the migration site* cannot apply.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Question (2) is about privaledges given **after** asking a question, like 'participate in meta' and 'comment everywhere'.  Do they affect the "new OP"'s ability to participate.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Thanks... looks great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get 0 results is that all answers get auto deleted once a question is migrated, while the question stays undeleted (but locked) for 30 days.

For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832703/what-is-the-right-way-to-pass-class-parameters-to-a-method?noredirect=1) got 9 answers before migration but all now deleted:

> [image]

Hence, as far as the search knows, all those questions have indeed 0 answers.

Worth also to mention that `migrated:yes` means questions that have been migrated from the site where you search to other site, that was likely the source of confusion as well.

As for your other question:

> Does migration of a question pose any technical hurdles to the Original Poster, if that OP does not yet have an account, on the migration-target-site?

The answer is no. The OP will simply have no account on the target site until he actively visits it and log in as usual, choosing the same OpenID provider. Then his new account on the target site will be associated with the account on the source site and the question will belong to him. All privileges are totally due to reputation he still need to earn, votes in the source site are being reset upon migration.

Comment: Agreed, but believe it or not, there are questions that are migrated **TO** stackoverflow... and it looks like none of them got answers.  Also, the same results happen on dba.stackexchange.com, where some of the migrations went:  zero results on `migrated:yes answers:1`

Comment: @Doug `migrated:yes` means "questions that have been migrated **from**  Stack Overflow to other site". I don't think there is search operator for the other direction. Data Explorer might contain that information, also not sure about that.

Comment: I think THAT's the answer to (1).  Edit/post it, and I'll accept it -- thanks!

Comment: OK, added to my post. :)

Comment: Accepted--thanks again--and summarized in a question edit.  Any thoughts on (2)? --- do missing abilities, like 'participate in meta' and 'comment everywhere' pose any hindrance to an OP, who is a raw new user on the target site?

Comment: @Doug will think of this and try to expand my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks, shady&wizardly, for speaking to question (2).  I've been thinking about it too, since our last comments, and I have one tentative & minor concern... that, if true, may be worth addressing:  I question whether the OP can *leave comments on answers*, equipped with a new account.  Normally, just asking a question, by itself, gives you enough points to attain that right (`comment everywhere`).  But on the migration-target site, is s/he not a new account without points for the question?  So, without `comment everywhere`, can he comment on *answers* to his own migrated question?

Comment: @Doug you got it wrong. User can always post comments on his own posts (both questions and answers) and on answers posted on his own question, that's even with 1 reputation. The "comment everywhere" is gained only when user get 50 reputation (it's 1 only here on this Meta).

Comment: @Doug now that the above is clear, when user whose question got migrated visit the target site and log in using the same credentials, his account will be automatically associated thus the question will be his by all means, as if he asked it on the target site, hence he can comment on it and on its answers just fine. :)